# How to match row data against an array of values

Tags: sql, ruby, sqlite

Is there a good way to check for matches in a SQL column, using an array of data, without having to loop as shown? Assume the url array has 100+ links, the below is just an example.

```
url = ["www.site1.com", "www.site2.com"]
url.each do |url|
    match = db.execute("SELECT 1 FROM ListData WHERE Link=? ", url)
    if match[0][0] == 1
       flag = true
    end
end
```

Comment: I'd recommend looking into using an ORM. They reduce the need to learn SQL and allow you concentrate on the code. Also, when it's time to move the code to another DBM an ORM can reduce the task to changing one line of code, rather than having to rewrite all your queries if the query-language isn't compatible. I'd recommend checking out [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net) and its [Cheat Sheet](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/cheat_sheet_rdoc.html).

Answer (score 2):

Use WHERE IN clause like this:

```
SELECT 1 FROM ListData WHERE Link IN ('www.site1.com','www.site2.com')
```

Comment: Assuming I have say 100+ links, can I just place the array directly in? db.execute("SELECT 1 FROM ListData WHERE Link IN url") I just need to know which urls are already in the database column

Comment: if you have that many links, you should insert them into the database and them join with them to filter. I assume you don't have 100k different links each time